# Iphone app links to app store but shows blank page instead of app to download

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, itunes

I´m making an app on iphone and i have a button that links to the appStore in order to download another app.

I´m using the code below that opens safari and instead of showing the twitter app the his on the link, show a blank page.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8"]];
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was using the simulator, it doesn´t have a app store so offcourse it wouldn´t show it... Guessing it will show on a real device.